# Jenkins pipeline, how to get sources from scm without Jenkins-file

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

i need to resolve some problem.
I need to build project in docker, without `Jenkinsfile`.
With `Jenkinsfile`, i can do something like this with `Definition: Pipeline script from SCM`

```
node('vm-docker') {
  stage('Get sources') {
     checkout scm
  }
  stage('Run in container')
  docker.image('maven:latest').inside {
    sh "mvn clean package"
  }
}
```

In this case, Jenkins downloads sources and Jenkins is using `Jenkinsfile` from this source. It works.

But the problem, that i can't push to this repo, only get. I tried to use `Definition: Pipeline script` with code:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'vm-docker'}

    stages {
        stage('Delete old sources') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Delete old sources"'
                sh '''
                    ls -lta
                    rm -rf myprogram
                    ls -lta
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Get sources') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Get sources"'
                sh '''
                    git clone git@github.com:myname/myprogram.git
                    cd myprogram
                    git checkout develop
                    git branch
                '''
            }
        }    
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'maven:latest' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

But in this case, Jenkins creates two separate workspaces and of course Jenkins can't make `mvn clean package`.

```
ls -lt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  6 Jul 21 16:12 my_job@2@tmp
drwxrwxr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  6 Jul 21 16:12 my_job@tmp
drwxrwxr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 18 Jul 21 16:12 my_job
drwxrwxr-x 2 jenkins jenkins  6 Jul 21 15:35 my_job@2
```

So, how i can resolve this ? How i can build my project in docker container, but without uploading to repository `Jenkinsfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Config `options` to skip clone the repo where Jenkinsfile resides.

```
pipeline {
  options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
}
```